# как парсить сайт с авторизацией

Tags: php, парсер, curl, авторизация

Надо спарсить контент на сайте после авторизации, но парсится только страница авторизации.

Вот код:

```
function get_content($url, $data = [])
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt');

    $c = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $c;
}

$auth_url = 'https://apiflash.com/login';
$url = 'https://apiflash.com/dashboard/access_keys';
$auth_data = [
    'email' => 'myEmail',
    'password' => 'myPassword',
];
$data = get_content($auth_url, $auth_data);
//var_dump($data);
$data = get_content($url);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: нужно авторизоваться, получить cookies и дальше их использовать

Comment: Есть несколько аккаунтов и скрипт должен сам авторизоваться

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: Суть в том что бы скрипт парсил аккаунты без меня, если я буду заходить на каждый из них и брать куку, в этом не смысла, я могу просто зайти и взять то что мне нужно, а не брать куки и парсить эту информацию

Comment: Так научите его это делать. Заходить, авторизироваться, получать куки и дальше парсить

Comment: Так я спрашиваю как это сделать

Comment: Здравтсвуйте, как решили проблему?